# List comprehensions work fine in Python shell but are ignored when running the script

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, slice

I have the following `d` `numpy` array:

```py
array([[0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4],
       [1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0],
       [4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0],
       [9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 4, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4]])
```

I need to fill another 2d array (`D`) with a Dynamic Time Warping algorithm, which requires filling the first row and the first column first, then the rest of the array.

To do so, I have a `DTWdistance(d)` function, which receives the `d` array above as argument to compute and return the new `D` array.

I'm intending to use list comprehensions over `for` loops, but while the loops work as expected, the list comprehensions are totally ignored when I run the script. They work fine when run in a Python shell, though, so any syntax errors can be discarded.

Since the lists comprehensions are being ignored, the `D` array is never computed, and the function is returning the same `d` array without any changes.

For example:

```py
D[0,1:] = [d[0,i] + D[0, i-1] for i in range(1, m)]
```

This should fill the first row of the `D` array (starting from `i=1`) with the following values: `[1, 5, 14, 18, 19, 19, 20, 24]`.

However, having this list comprehension for the first row and `for` loops for the rest of the process, it yields the `D` array with every value correct, ***except*** for the first row, which isn't changing anything and instead of assigning the list above to the array slice, it's simply assingning those values from the corresponding slice of the `d` array: `[1, 4, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4]`.

In consequence, by using lists comprehensions to compute the whole `D` array I'm getting nothing but the same `d` array.

I'm well aware of the existence of several DTW-oriented tools out there, but this is my own implementation, which fits a particular set of personal needs.

I would appreciate explanations about why the list comprehensions are being ignored, and if I may be doing something wrong or if this could be a bug, and how I can overcome it.

I'm using Python 3.4 x64, and Spyder IDE 2.3.5.2, on Windows 8.

---

**TL;DR:**

Tried to use list comprehensions instead of loops to calculate several lists and assign them to specific slices of a 2d array. They work fine in the Python shell but are ignored if run in script. I have no idea why.

---

As requested, an MCVE:

```py
import numpy as np

def ldistance(x, y):
    m = len(x)
    n = len(y)

    # Euclidean distance
    d = np.array([[(x[j]-y[i])**2 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)],
             dtype=float)
    return d

def cdistance(d):
    n, m = d.shape
    D = np.zeros((n, m))

    # First element is identical in both matrices.
    D[0, 0] = d[0, 0]
    # Elements in first row [0, 1:]
    D[0, 1:] = [d[0, j] + D[0, j-1] for j in range(1, m)]
    # Elements in first column [1:, 0]
    D[1:, 0] = [d[i, 0] + D[i-1, 0] for i in range(1, n)]
    # Rest of the elements in the matrix [1:, 1:]
    D[1:, 1:] = [[d[i, j] + min(D[i-1, j-1], D[i-1, j], D[i, j-1])
                 for j in range(1, m)]
                 for i in range(1, n)]
    return D

# --

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
y = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0]

d = ldistance(x, y)
D = cdistance(d)
```

Comment: can you give a complete working program that illustrates the problem? See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I fail to see how `D[0, 1:] = [d[0, j] + D[0, j-1] for j in range(1, m)]` can possibly fill in the entries of `D` correctly. `D[0, j-1]` is just going to be zero for most of the comprehension since the results aren't going to be assigned until the entire comprehension is computed.

Comment: Is numpy really required to illustrate this problem? The question reads as if this is strictly about a list comprehension. Can you not just create a list with some static data, then create a comprehension based on that list? Or are the values in that list part of the problem?

Comment: @nneonneo: So is anything of what I'm trying to do achievable with list comprehensions?

Comment: ...nope. I'm actually not even sure how this can work on the Python shell. Just write some plain for-loops to fill in your array, since the values from each iteration depend on the results of prior iterations.

Comment: @BryanOakley: The values are just to illustrate how both matrices are yielded the same. The algorithm goes: input two lists, calculate local distance (`ldistance()`) of each value, then calculate cumulative distance (`cdistance()`) based on local disance.

Comment: Alright, good to know this is a wrong approach. I'll stick to `for` loops then. Thanks for the comments, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong part here, is that you can't do this sort of thing:

```
D[0, 1:] = [d[0, j] + D[0, j-1] for j in range(1, m)]
```

As you can see you are trying to use an element on D, which would be calculated
inside this inner loop in itself (the `D[0, j-1]` part). `D[0, 1:]` is only calculated after the whole list expression is evaluated and the resulting list assigned to `D[0: 1:]` - so, but for the value of `j == 1` where you have already assigned `D[0, 0]`, all the remaining values `D[0, j-1]` are 0.

If you, by chance, ever had this working on he interactive mode, it could only be because you had previously filled D with meaningful values.

Performing external `for` loops will work in this case, because the previous, needed values of D items will already have been assigned when you are computing the values depending on that.

Comment: "If you, by chance, ever had this working on he interactive mode, it could only be because you had previously filled D with meaningful values." - Yes, that was indeed it since I'm using Spyder and it keeps all the global variables stored, including the `D` array and its values. Thanks for the complete explanation, it makes much more sense now.